# Rerun entire Test Suite if a Test Case Fails in Robot Framework

Tags: cookies, robotframework

Is there a way to rerun entire Test Suite if a single Particular test case fails .

So for example , a Robot Code which contain a test case which  will check the cookie value , if the cookie is of a particular pattern will continue execution of rest of code , if it fails it should rerun the entire Robot Code / Test Suite and repeat this 3 times , if the cookie value is not same for three runs , let it fail the test suite completely  .

Answer (score 0):

You can run original test, rerun failed and merge the results of both runs. If some tests are failed in the first run and then pass in the second, you will see that in the results.

> There is often a need to re-execute a subset of tests, for example,
> after fixing a bug in the system under test or in the tests
> themselves. This can be accomplished by selecting test cases by names
> (--test and --suite options), tags (--include and --exclude), or by
> previous status (--rerunfailed or --rerunfailedsuites).

```
robot --output original.xml tests                                # first execute all tests
robot --rerunfailedsuites original.xml --output rerun.xml tests  # then re-execute failing
rebot --merge original.xml rerun.xml                             # finally merge results
```

You can read more about this in here https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#merging-re-executed-tests

To your specific example, I am not sure that you can do that. But you can save the exit code of the run and evaluate it base on that

```
robot "your robot options" $@
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then 
"evaluation options when passed"
fi
else
"evaluation options when failed"
fi
```

Comment: Sorry , it's not like i just want to run only failed test case , if a particular test case fails , i have to start run entire file again . Is there any way to achieve it

Comment: the option --rerunfailedsuites reruns the entire suite, not just the test.

Comment: but i want it to run only if one specific / Particular case fails . this will run if any of the test case fails na ?

Comment: That is quite unusual, however you can use keyword **Run Keyword If Test Failed** in test teardown. Use this to log to file, based on the content of this file execute robot command with your specific suite. This way only if the specific test fails, the suit will be executed.

Comment: Another way would be to use tags, and tag the other tests as uncritical. Then you can use the  **--rerunfailedsuites**  option and the suite should only rerun after your specific test fails. For information about tags, have a look at 
https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#tagging-test-cases
Then you can assign criticality to the tag. The documentation is here
https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#setting-criticality

Comment: so am using pabot for parallel running , can i use same command for pabot too