# Executing Python Script from Robot Framework : FAILS

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a robot framework code that should re-execute entire test suite if a single test case fails . So for achieving that , i ran a python script inside Robot Framework code that will re execute the code once again . But i am not able to do that
Posting my code below :

```
***Settings***
Variables  DailyRun

*** Variables ***
${InstanceName}   abvsu

*** Test Cases ***
CookieTest
    sleep  10 sec
    ${CookieValue}   Get Cookie    tmsprd103842
    Log To Console  ${CookieValue.value}
    ${b}=    Get Regexp Matches    ${CookieValue.value}   abc
    Set Global Variable  ${b}
    Run Keyword if   ${b} != '[abc]'   Loginafterfail

*** Keywords ***
Loginafterfail
#    Close Browser
    ${result}=  run process       python       DailyRun.py
    Log to Console   ${result.stdout}
```

and Python Script looks like this :

```
def Callingfunction(IntsanceName):

    date_time = datetime.now().strftime("%m%d%Y-%H%M%S")
    log_time = "TestResult-" + date_time
    for i in range(0, 1):
        os.system(
            'cmd /c "robot '+IntsanceName+'.robot "'
        )
def main():
    Callingfunction()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

But Here this re-execution of the code after CookieTest fails , is not working

Answer (score 0):

please have a look at the answer of your previous question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/65247970/13713938
running the robot with option **--output original.xml** will give you all you need.

```
robot --output original.xml tests
```

Your case this is the step in your runner

```
os.system(
    'cmd /c "robot --output original.xml '+IntsanceName+'.robot "'
)
```

You then run add next step to your runner this step reruns all failed suites, not just the test.

```
robot --rerunfailedsuites original.xml --output rerun.xml tests
```

for you this would interpret as somethink like this.

```
os.system(
    'cmd /c "robot --rerunfailedsuites original.xml --output rerun.xml '+IntsanceName+'.robot "'
)
```

Finaly you just merge the two xml files

```
rebot --merge original.xml rerun.xml

os.system(
    'cmd /c "rebot --merge original.xml rerun.xml "'
)
```

You can read more about this topic in the manual https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#merging-re-executed-tests